# How do I add normalize-space into my psql query statement to remove \302\240 from my query results

Tags: normalize-space

This is my blob statement

```
(xpath('/d:Invoice/d:InvoiceDetail/d:InvoiceLineItem/d:LineItemDescription/text()',
                             xml,
                             
      '{{d,http://www.m00.com/2019/01/RRRInvoice}}'))[1]::text as Line_ItemDescription,
```